# How to make use of Terraform conditons like count?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

I want to make use of count or any condition that helps me create resources when i use that specific condition. But i am not understanding the concept yet. can anyone post any helpful link or explain it through an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Count](https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/count.html) is a Terraform meta-parameter. It makes you create multiple copies of resources by simply incrementing a number. To accomplish the same thing in Terraform, you can use `count.index` to get the index of each instance in the loop.

Usually, you can use `Count` and [Conditional Expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (`condition ? true_val : false_val`) to dynamically create your resources.

Here are some useful links and examples

- https://azurecitadel.com/automation/terraform/lab4/
- https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux-academy/using-count-for-cleaner-terraform/
- https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9#0223

### Update

Here is a working sample to [enable the private Azure Kubernetes Service cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters). This creates 2 AKS clusters of which one should be private. The rest of the configuration is the same.

```
variable "prefix" {
  default = "nancyaks"
}

variable "custom_aks" {
  description = "Custom tags to set on the Instances in the ASG"
  type        = map(string)
  default = {
    "aks1" = true
    "aks2" = false
  }
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

# add advanced networking information 
# resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
#   name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
#   location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
#   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
#   address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
# }

# resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
#   name                 = "internal"
#   resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
#   address_prefixes       = ["10.1.0.0/22"]
#   virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
# }


resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  for_each            = var.custom_aks
  name                = "${var.prefix}-${each.key}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  dns_prefix          = "${var.prefix}-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "acctestuser1"
    ssh_key {
      key_data = file(var.public_ssh_key_path)
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
        name            = "agentpool"
        node_count      = 2
        vm_size         = "Standard_DS1_v2"
        //vnet_subnet_id  = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    }

  private_cluster_enabled = each.value

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
  }
}
```

**result**

[image]

Comment: I want to create 2 AKS clusters of which one should be private. The rest of the configuration is the same. How can i make use of count parameter to create these two.

Comment: Instead of using `count`, I think using `for_each` is easy to deploy dynamic block. The `count` is better to deploy identical resources. See this [example1](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Terraform/Terraform-Introduction-AWS-loops.php) and [example2](https://dev.to/drewmullen/terraform-use-foreach-instead-of-count-27e)